# Add app to favorites of facebook page

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-page, favorites

I saw there where already some toppics about this, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

On the facebook page of tetris, you can see a button which links to the tetris app.
http://www.facebook.com/tetrisbattle?fref=ts
(right beneath the banner)

I made a page to, but I couldn't find how to make this button.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

Goto your app's "App Details" settings in the App Dashboard:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOURAPPID/appdetails

Under the Contact Info part of that page, there is an 'App Page' field, with a button to create an App Page. You should click on this and create the Facebook Page that way. Once you do, there will be a button on the Page that will either say "Go to App" or "Play Game" depending on how your Facebook app is categorised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I already tried this, but facebook asks a lot of info of me, before the page can be made.
Since this is a school-assignment, I don't have privacy policy's and so on. Is there another way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found another way. You can see it down here!

Answer (score 0):

I searched a little bit more, and I've found an answer to my own question.

In this link, you have to give your app id, and the link to your app.
Then a facebook popup comes, and asks you on which page you want to add this app.
http://admine.eu/addapp.html